Require explicit resource input in Azure pipeline
Whan I run a pipeline without specifying an external resource in the pipeline it runs anyway with the defaults as configured in the .yml file:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipelineA
    source: 'A'
    branch: master
    trigger: none
  - pipeline: PipelineB
    source: 'B'
    branch: master
    trigger: none

Is there any way I can enforce providing the resources from the azure web UI when requesting without resorting to some bogus defaults that will fail the run when not overridden?


Is there any way I can enforce providing the resources from the azure web UI when requesting without resorting to some bogus defaults that will fail the run when not overridden?

Yes. I suggest that you can use Runtime Parameters to force users to input the resources version(version: buildnumber) to override the Pipeline resource default value.
Here is an example:
parameters:
- name: PipelineAVersion
  type: string

- name: PipelineBVersion
  type: string

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipelineA
    source: 'A'
    branch: master
    version: ${{parameters.PipelineAVersion}}
    trigger: none
  - pipeline: PipelineB
    source: 'B'
    branch: master
    version: ${{parameters.PipelineBVersion}}
    trigger: none

When we run the Pipeline, it will force user to input the Pipeline version of the resource.

If you don't provide the required version parameters, it will not run the pipeline and show the following errors:

A value for the 'parameter' parameter must be provided.


Note:  The version field in the pipeline resources needs to input the Build Number value of the pipeline.
Refer to this doc: resources.pipelines.pipeline definition

Looks good, although I hoped to add the requirement to the "resource picker" instead of a manually written field.

@Zitrax Yes. I can fully understand your requirement. But if we use resource picker in pipeline run, we are not able to force users to choose for the time being.  Currently we can only force user to input through parameters in YAML Pipeline. I suggest that you can submit a feature request ticket in this ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest

You can use the resource version picker to manually choose a different version when you create a run:

Available resources:

Selecting a pipeline:

The resource version picker is supported for pipeline, build, repository, container, and package resources.
See Manual version picker for resources for more details.

Yes we already use this, the problem is to enforce it, i.e. not allowing to run without picking the resource.

@Zitrax in that case it will pick the default version. I'm not sure if understand your problem - do you want to ensure the default version is always a valid build? You can add other filters such as stages and/or tags.

No, I want to not allow any default values forcing the user to select a resource. I.e. at the moment you are allowed to start the run without having picked a resource. I could check it inside the pipeline, but optimally I would like to enforce it already in the UI.
